# How to get text with XPath from inside an XML which appears as text inside a html page?

Tags: xml, xpath

My question is that would it be possible to search XML nodes if the whole XML appear inside a `html` tag as a text?
Just to be more clear I'll show you a very simple example of what I would like to do.

```
<pre id='x'> 
 <a> 
<b> text1 </b> 
<c>      
<d> text2 </d> 
</c> 
<e> 
<f> text3 </f> 
<g> text4 </g> 
</e> 
</a> 
</pre>
```

The whole XML is inside a  `<pre>`    `html` tag.
Would it be possible to get the text of any of these nodes (b,d,f,g)? Like 'text1', 'text2' etc? Since this is a text, I couldn't figure out how to do this with xpath...
Could you please help me with this if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class testXML {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File input = new File("D:\\test.xml");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(doc.select("pre").select("d").text());
}

}
```

**Output:**
text2

Answer (score 0):

`//pre[@id="x"]//*/text()` if you want the text content of all of `pre` descendants. Or `//pre[@id="x"]//b/text()` if you want just `b` contents.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the answer but unfortunately this isn't working. Maybe I wasn't too clear but the      <pre>     element doesn't have descendants since all the other tags (a,b,c,d) are rendered as text on the html page. I could have easily ask that how to get a text inside a text. Like the following:     `<p> this is text a. this is value b. this is value c. this is value d.    <p>`    So, how to get the text after one of the values word? Like b,c or d. Obviously I don't know what this values are. Hopefully this was more clear. Thank you

Comment: Oh, so <pre> actually contain escaped data (or CDATA section)? Then you would need to select it with `//pre[@id="x"]/text()`, and then interpret the result as a document fragment, on which you can run separate xpath queries. I don't think this can be done with XPath alone.